# Js made search function not working on dynamically created content from database

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<% include layouts/header %>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/ac.css">
<h1>Downloads available</h1>
<br><br>
<input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Search for names..">
<br><br>
<div class="row" id = "row">
  <%
  if(output){
  siz = output.length;
  for(i=0;i<siz;++i){
  %>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4" id = "col">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src = "<%= output[i].logo %>" alt="...">
        <div class="caption">
          <h3><%= output[i].name %></h3>
          <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
          <p id = "clk"><a href="/pages/<%= output[i].lid %>" style= "width:100%;" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <%
  }
}else{
  console.log("ERror");
}
  %>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  function myFunction() {
    input = document.getElementById('myInput');
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    col = document.getElementById("col");
    li = col.getElementsByClassName('thumbnail');

    // Loop through all list items, and hide those who don't match the search query
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        h = li[i].getElementsByTagName("h3")[0];
        if (h.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
  }

  $("#myInput").on("keyup",function(){
    myFunction();
  });

  $("p").on("click",function(){
    window.open('http://facebook.com', '_blank');
  });
});

</script>
<% include layouts/footer %>
```

In this page I have made a search bar which should search through the dynamically created content on the page.But it is not working for all the thumbnails. It search only the first thumbnail and there is no effect on the other thumbnails.

I know javascript loads before the HTML... So i have used $(document).ready function in order to load javascript after HTML.

I also got a solution to use ".on" event handler but it did not help. The result remains same.

Comment: Your for loop is repeating ids inside it.  Those should be classes instead, since ids must be unique within a page.  So at least part of your issue is with your use of the repeated `col` id.

Comment: Adding to @Taplar 's comment When querying for an id, it generally stops after the first one that it found, because they are supposed to be unique.

Comment: Thanxx it helped :)